# Loaded a script to /bin, then deleted, but still works

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I created a simple shell called glang then made it executable.
$ chmod +x glang
Then I copied it into /bin
$ sudo cp glang /bin
I made it work. However, then I wanted to delete it and went to /bin
$ cd /bin
Then delete it.
$ sudo rm glang
And when I listed files, I couldn't find the script, then I thought it's been deleted.
However, when I still write 
$ glang
any where in the file system, the script still works!
Any idea whats going on?
Thanks in advance.

Content of glang is as follows(It's basically a preprocessor thing):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 >> ~/lexer/var.cl
echo "\")" >> ~/lexer/var.cl
cat ~/lexer/var.cl >> ~/lexer/exe.cl
cat ~/lexer/char_processing.cl >> ~/lexer/exe.cl
cat ~/lexer/io_processing.cl >> ~/lexer/exe.cl
cat ~/lexer/lex_processing.cl >> ~/lexer/exe.cl
cat ~/lexer/main.cl >> ~/lexer/exe.cl
clisp ~/lexer/exe.cl
```

Comment: what the commnd `which glang` returns?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Your update is not related to the results of `which` or `whereis` command. Run `which` or `whereis` and update your question with the results of those commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
whereis <script name>
```

Comment: Thanks! I found it /usr/bin. I was looking it at /bin. What's the difference between them anyway?

Comment: Pleasem could you mark my question as the correct answer? /bin is for executables that are provided by the system, /usr/bin is for executabes provided by your system package manager (apt, dnf, yum, pacman, etc...), and /usr/local/bin is for executables provided by the user or other apps. You should use /usr/local/bin next time.

Answer (score 0):

Under linux you should use `/usr/local/bin` for custom scripts that you create. That location is in the PATH and you can use your script from that location. So it's not a good idea to replace the "buildin" scripts. You can call the buildin script with:

```
buildin glang
```

If the scripts are installed over the package manager you can search with `which` or `whereis`. When you use the same name like the original one you can get problems. So you should give them another name.